# Consumir webservice soap com PHP (xml com atributos)

Tags: php, web-service, xml

Preciso consumir uma wsdl porem o XML para envio ao servidor do webservice possui atributos. Criei um array contendo todos as tags, porem fiquei na duvida de como adicionar os atributos de cada tag.

*XML que deve ser enviado ao servidor:*

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' xmlns:ws='http://ws.document.general.modules.opengtm.com.br/'>
                    <soapenv:Header/>
                    <soapenv:Body>
                            <ws:receiveDocument>
                                    <ws:login>user@company.com</ws:login>
                                    <ws:password>123</ws:password>
                                    <ws:xmlDocument>
                                            <![CDATA[
                                                    <documents>
                                                            <document code='959559' operationDate='01/05/2018 12:21:00' isTicket='false' type='EN' fullWeight='38544' vehicleWeight='15870'>
                                                                    <owner document='23117229000106' name='SEND PHP' />
                                                                    <truck code='KAZ' serial='2931' />
                                                                    <carrier document='18822165000104' name='Reitran Transportes Ltda Me' />
                                                                    <item amount='1' lot='CAR' weight='22674'>
                                                                            <product code='102540' description='CAR BLACK' />
                                                                    </item>
                                                            </document>
                                                    </documents>
                                            ]]>
                                    </ws:xmlDocument>
                            </ws:receiveDocument>
                    </soapenv:Body>
                  </soapenv:Envelope>";
```

*Meu Array*

```
$lst = array('receiveDocument' => array("login" => "user@company.comr",
                "password" => "123",
                "xmlDocument" => array(array("documents" => array("document" => (array('code' => '959580', 'operationDate' => '01/05/2018 12:21:00', 'isTicket' => 'false', 'type' => 'EN', 'fullWeight' => '38544', 'vehicleWeight' => '15870',
                        array(
                            array("owner" => array('document' => '23117229000106', 'name' => 'SEND PHP')),
                            array("truck" => array('code' => 'KAZ', 'serial' => '2931')),
                            array("carrier" => array('document' => '18822165000104', 'name' => 'Reitran Transportes Ltda Me')),
                            array("item" => array('amount' => '1', 'lot' => 'CAR', 'weight' => '22674', array("product" => array('code' => '102540', 'description' => 'CAR BLACK'))))))
                            ))))
            )
        );
        try {

            $url = 'http://192.168.0.89:8980/app/services/integrationDocument?WSDL';
            $webService = new \SoapClient($url);
            $result = $webService->receiveDocument($lst);
            dd($result);
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            echo $exception->getMessage();
        }
```

Comment: usando curl não é menos dificil? qual o retorno que vc vai receber?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apesar de ser uma questão que já está no SO há um tempo, carece de uma resposta. Vamos lá.

Ao consumir um WebService, deve-se estar ciente de que os parâmetros definidos no WSDL (tanto para envio quanto para retorno) não possuem atributos, pois, o WS não os suporta (com uma única exceção [`RPC/Encoded`](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/ws-whichwsdl/index.html#N1006A), mas ai é algo bem específico).

Ou seja, o XML interno, que possui atributos, nada mais é que uma string de um XML.

Neste caso, os parâmetros devem ser enviados de forma similar a:

```
$xmlDocument = "<documents>
                    <document code='959559' operationDate='01/05/2018 12:21:00' isTicket='false' type='EN' fullWeight='38544' vehicleWeight='15870'>
                        <owner document='23117229000106' name='SEND PHP' />
                        <truck code='KAZ' serial='2931' />
                        <carrier document='18822165000104' name='Reitran Transportes Ltda Me' />
                        <item amount='1' lot='CAR' weight='22674'>
                            <product code='102540' description='CAR BLACK' />
                        </item>
                    </document>
                </documents>";

$lst = array(
    'receiveDocument' => array(
        "login" => "user@company.comr",
        "password" => "123",
        "xmlDocument" => new \SoapParam(new \SoapVar($xmlDocument , XSD_ANYXML) , 'param')
    )
);
```

Devido a não possuir acesso ao WSDL completo do seu WS, outro ponto que deve ser considerado é analisar se o `SOAP Binding` é estilo (`style`) `document` ou `RPC` (*Remote Procedure Call*). Pois, analisando apenas a mensagem de envio (que é o seu exemplo), o nó `receiveDocument` pode ser tanto o nome do método (caso o `style` seja `RPC`) como pode ser um parâmetro do método (caso o `style` seja `document`).

A forma de consumir, apresentada no código anterior, é para quando o `binding` for `style="document"`. Por outro lado, a chamada, com os parâmetros, para `style="RPC"` seria:

```
$xmlDocument = "<documents>
                    <document code='959559' operationDate='01/05/2018 12:21:00' isTicket='false' type='EN' fullWeight='38544' vehicleWeight='15870'>
                        <owner document='23117229000106' name='SEND PHP' />
                        <truck code='KAZ' serial='2931' />
                        <carrier document='18822165000104' name='Reitran Transportes Ltda Me' />
                        <item amount='1' lot='CAR' weight='22674'>
                            <product code='102540' description='CAR BLACK' />
                        </item>
                    </document>
                </documents>";

$xmlParam = new \SoapParam(new \SoapVar($xmlDocument , XSD_ANYXML) , 'param');

$login = "user@company.comr";
$password = "123";


try {

    $url = 'http://192.168.0.89:8980/app/services/integrationDocument?WSDL';
    $webService = new \SoapClient($url);
    $result = $webService->receiveDocument($login , $password , $xmlParam);
    dd($result);
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    echo $ex->getMessage();
}
```